# Disable default apache error pages

Tags: apache, api, http-status-code-400

I am creating an API that is being accessed through apache. My API is designed to return http status error codes when there was an issue with the request. For example if the API consumer sends on invalid date format as a query parameter the API server will respond with something like this.

Http Status Code: 400
Body:

```
{
   message: "Invalid date format"
}
```

However apache seems to be replacing the body with this error page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

How can I prevent apache from replacing the response?

Note: If the Http Status Code is set to 200 by the API the reponse body returns as expected.

Adding more context: It is an angular app served from apache, that proxies to tomcat for api requests, and the client should handle the error messages instead of serving a static page from apache.

Comment: Apache alone is not sufficient to build an API, but you've told us nothing about what what sits behind Apache, nor shown us the code its running.

Comment: Tomcat is running the code using Spring MVC

Comment: Does that mean you're not running Apache httpd at all but are referring to Tomcat when you say "Apache"?

Comment: Sorry, running Apache httpd that redirects to Apache Tomcat

Comment: Try to setup ProxyErrorOverride to off in ssl.conf.

Answer (score 1):

Trick is to remap apache's default 400 Bad request error page to your public entry
to ignore the http ssl error then using .htaccess file to force https

**default-ssl.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
    ErrorDocument 400 /var/www/html/public/index.php
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/default.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/default.key
</VirtualHost>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following the [docs here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html) to specify custom error pages for apache / httpd.

i.e., put this in your *.htaccess*, or httpd.conf site definition.

for static response:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error/static400.json
```

or even dynamic

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error/doSomething.php
```

A 400 means that apache did not understand the request, and it is likely it never even made it to whatever application lives behind the webserver.

Comment: The json file is not static but dynamically created by the api server

Comment: Then point it to something else... But that is the config option you will need to use.

Comment: The request is making it to the server (Tomcat in this case). The response is created correctly by tomcat and sent back to the browser. However the response body is replaced before reaching the browser